# How can I use a variable from xstring with the text along path decoration from tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, expansion, decorations

## Issue

How can I get proper text expansion for `text=\somevariable` in a `tikz` text decoration. I think I have an expansion problem here.

1. Set `\releasedate`
2. Extract year from `\releasedate` in `\manufacturedate`
3. Set `\manufacturedate` as value to `text=` in `decoration={}`

I attempted to solve this with

`\begingroup\expandarg\manufacturedate{}\endgroup`. <- unsure about this.

## Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.text}

\newcommand\textthatpath[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=10cm]
    \node (data) {Data};
    \node [right=of data] (app) {App};
    % Lines
    \draw [<->,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={#1}}}]  (data) to[out=90,in=90] (app);
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\newcommand{\releasedate}{2015-03-27}
\newcommand\manufacturedatetext{%
    \StrLeft{\releasedate}{4}[\productiondate]
    \productiondate
}%

\newcommand\decotext{© Specialized Services GmbH \manufacturedatetext{}} 

\begin{document}
    %\textthatpath{\decotext{}} % This does not work, but I am hoping to get it working.
    \manufacturedatetext{}  % This prints \productiondate
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell `xstring` to do the expansion for you via `\fullexpandarg` or another lighter setting described in the manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.text}

\newcommand{\releasedate}{2015-03-27}
\newcommand\manufacturedatetext{%
{\fullexpandarg
    \StrLeft{\releasedate}{4}[\productiondate]\productiondate%
}
}%
\newcommand\decotext{© Specialized Services GmbH \manufacturedatetext{}} 


\newcommand\textthatpath[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=10cm]
    \node (data) {Data};
    \node [right=of data] (app) {App};
    % Lines
    \draw [<->,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={#1}}}]  (data) to[out=90,in=90] (app);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}
    \textthatpath{\decotext} % This does not work, but I am hoping to get it working.
    \manufacturedatetext{}  % This prints \productiondate
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What a relief. That was driving me nuts!